# Why is my attempt to have a form submitted not doing anything?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a website that has a form to submit. However, even tho I've now got a http://formspree.io/ that can forward to me, and did forward to me when I had:

```
            <form action="http://formspree.io/myaddress@gmail.com" method="post">
                <label for="Name">Name</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="Name"/><br/>
                <label for="emailAddress">E-Mail address</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="emailAddress"/><br/>
                <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.."></textarea><br/>
                <input type="submit" name="SUBMIT"/>
            </form>
```

I decided to make React components to create a stateful model to submit the form. However, when I hit the submit button, it does nothing, and also I don't know how to get it to change whats on the page. My code is:

```
 handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let userData = this.state.newUser;

    fetch('http://formspree.io/myAddress@gmail.com', {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(userData),
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }).then(response => {
      response.json().then(data => {
        console.log("Successful" + data);
      });
    });
  }
```

My imports and constructor are:

```
import Input from "./FormComponents/Input";
import TextArea from "./FormComponents/TextArea";
import Select from "./FormComponents/Select";
import Button from "./FormComponents/Button";

class FormContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      newUser: {
        name: "",
        email: "",
        location: "",
        message: ""
      },

      locationOptions: ['(outside the USA', 'AL', 'AK', 'AS', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'DC', 'FM', 'FL', 'GA', 'GU', 'HI', 
      'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'ME', 'MH', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 
      'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'MP', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PW', 'PA', 'PR', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 
      'UT', 'VT', 'VI', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY' ]


    };
    this.handleTextArea = this.handleTextArea.bind(this);
    this.handleFullName = this.handleFullName.bind(this);
    this.handleEmailAddress = this.handleEmailAddress.bind(this);
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleClearForm = this.handleClearForm.bind(this);
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
  }
```

why is nothing happening when the Submit button is hit?

Comment: Why has this question be voted down?

Answer (score 0):

```
handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let userData = this.state.newUser;

    fetch('http://formspree.io/myAddress@gmail.com', {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(userData),
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }).then(response => {
      response.json().then(data => {
        console.log("Successful" + data);
      });
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('post error', error);
     });
  }
```

You should be able to see what is wrong.

Comment: I'm getting: `Access to fetch at 'http://formspree.io/myAddress@gmail.com' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
FormContainer.jsx:108 post error TypeError: Failed to fetch` and then when I put `{mode : cors}` as an arg to fetch, I get `GET https://formspree.io/myAddress@gmail.com 405
FormContainer.jsx:104 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at FormContainer.jsx:104`

Comment: Use the Chrome dev tools to see your request contents. https://www.mkyong.com/computer-tips/how-to-view-http-headers-in-google-chrome/. On the filter bar, click on XHR to only get ajax requests (I guess your fetch() method sends an ajax request)

Comment: I see a 405 method; could it be that formspree doesn't allow this? this is what I'm using `https://formspree.io/` @user2343647

Comment: in full, `Status Code: 405 
Remote Address: [2606:4700:20::6819:a424]:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade`